# Promises in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, promise

I try to load `json` file with `angularjs`, `$q` and return data from `angular` filter.

I have a angular filter:

```
MyApp.filter('my_filter', function ($q){
    return function(input){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var j = {};

        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
            j = json;
            deferred.resolve(json);
        });

        return j;
```

But i got `{}`. How can i synchronously load `json` and return it's content from filter?

Thank you.

Comment: Before I answer, can I assume you're _NOT_ using JSONP to load your JSON?

Comment: Why i must use JSONP? I got json file from my server, it's ok.

Comment: NONO, the fact you're not using JSONP is __GOOD__ , I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Why not just use angular's $http? It will return the response in a promise for you. You shouldn't be doing this directly in a filter. You should move this to a service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can do this synchronously

AngularJS uses jqLite, you can create a normal `GET` request with `.ajax` and pass it an `async:false` flag just like in jQuery. One way to make all your AJAX synchronous would be:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

You can also do this in the options section of any request.

### But you shouldn't

Really, AJAX is asynchronous by design, JavaScript *thrives* on performing async i/o it's why it's an awesome language. If you perform synchronous ajax the screen will *freeze* until the AJAX will arrive which will create a very bad user experience.

What I'd do is return a promise from the AJAX performing method, when it resolves have it update another scope variable, and filter *that* instead. Better yet, you can write the code above as:

```
 return $.getJSON(url);
```

Avoid the deferred altogether. Using that deferred is called [the deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: Also, getJSON returns a promise, so there really is no reason in wrapping it in another deferred in these cases normally.

Answer (score 0):

`getJSON` works async. I suggest you to use `ajax` instead.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
}).done( function(json) {
  j = json;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the promise that is reside inside the deferred object. What you need to do is replace your return code with:

```
return deferred.promise;
```

Explanation: Promises are a very good way to handle async code. What you like to do is return to the calling function a promise that say something like "I give you this promise that when my callback function will return I return a result" and when the callback is executed later on you should (and actually rightfully do) resolve the deferred with the data you like to return. This resolve call activate the "**then**" function that is chained to the promise you have returned.

On the receiving function you should "wait" on the promise to be resolved, something like:

```
functionThatReturnPromise()
.then(function(result){
    //This is a handler function that called when you call "**deferred.resolve(json)**" so **result** object will hold the **json** object.
...})
.then(function(result){
    //Here you can chain promises as much as you want because "**then**" return the same promise.
})
.catch(function(err){
    //If instead of "**deferred.resolve(json)**" you will call "**deferred.reject(someErr)**" you will end up in this handler function
}
```